# MySQLi persistant connections filling concurrent users

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I work for a company that has recently updated the PHP code for a site from vanilla MySQL to MySQLi to be ahead of the deprecation changes.

We had some issues with MySQL using 64k of source TCP ports at the network level and falling over. We fixed that by enabling persistent connections. 
However, we now have a new issue which is the queries we run don't always reuse existing connections and end up filling up all of the connection slots (200).

The setup we run is thus:

We have mutiple DB servers (4 in the dev environment) with replicated tables and single databases for each client site distributed over the servers (each site has its own schema) for performance.

We have a custom query parsing function that determines which host to connect to, selects the correct schema and runs the query against. This isn't the issue, this all works fine.

The master DB server is getting hammered with connections, fills up then refuses any new connections.

There is only ever 1 call of mysqli_connect made per host required for each page load. But for some reason the connections never seem to be reused. even refreshing the same page a few times creates new connections for each load.

Is this normal? I would have expected reloading the same page and fetching the same data would reused the sleeping connections that were created before the refresh..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is normal. You should read the [warnings on persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php). The first paragraph is usually enough to scare you away. In other languages persistent connections worked as you would expect.

When you view the mysql processes on the db server, do you see a lot of idle connections? You may want to reduce the mysql [wait timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) value to drop idle connections. I'm usually fairly aggressive on this setting (30 secs) and have scaled systems decently (1M page views a day).

To really be ahead of the deprecation change, you should consider going to PDO. Shameless plug: I wrote [my own db class](https://github.com/shutterstock/basecoat/blob/master/basecoat/classes/db.php) that manages connections, connects on demand or reconnects as needed. This allows very low timeout settings without worrying about dropped connections.

Comment: Other parts of the system (dataload) uses PDO but we don't have the allowance of time to rebuild the entire data layer of the product, its a pretty hefty product with many, maanny queries. MySQLi was a short route to stay ahead of deprecation

Ideally, we would like to not use persistence but also not fill up all of the source TCP ports. I don't know if there is a middleground.

Comment: I'm in a similar state with another project. Reducing the wait timeout on MySQL has worked for me. Persistent connections can actually make things worse.

Comment: They have indeed made things worse. The alternative however is opening about 5000 TCP source ports per page load. If we run a query against a peer that has 150 source databases for example. it opens over 65k connections and then nothing else can do anything.

Comment: I don't follow. You should establish 1 connection per database server (not database), per page load. On a site with 400K daily page views, my master and slave db servers hover around 100 connections each. How many db servers in prod do you have?

Comment: In production we have 1 master (with site databases on it also) and 4 slaves. The problem is we deal with data/statistics for clients involving peers. Any particular page load, depending where they are looking could fire 150 queries spread over all the servers via CURL then the data is collated and displayed. It's quite complicated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a caching layer, throttling, and/or more slaves. The it is complicated is usually an indication it's the wrong setup.